# Can't get Express router to work

Tags: javascript, node.js, web

I'm currently getting into NodeJS in my free time and I tried to set up a simple project to play around with Node and GraphQL by splitting things into module as much as possible, which leads me 
[to this folder structure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSqpP.png)

The issue I'm running into is that none of the routes defined via Express get triggered. The page just loads forever until it times out, and the log messages don't get printed to the server's console.
Here's the code for the server's entry point:

```
// index.js
const appConfig = require('./config');
const express = require('express');
var app = express();

// Set up configuration variables according to the current execution environment
const environment = appConfig.environment;
const config = appConfig[environment];
const defaultPort = config.app.port;
const logLevel = config.app.logLevel;

// Set up modules
const logger = require('./src/logger')('server', logLevel);
const db = require('./src/db')(config);
const handler = require('./src/handler')(db);
const routes = require('./src/routes')(handler);

// Set up routes
app.use('/', routes);

// Start listening
const server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || defaultPort, function() {
    const port = server.address().port;
    logger.log('info', 'App now listening to port ' + port);
});
```

And the routing module:

```
// src/routes/index.js
const logger = require('../logger')('routes');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

module.exports = function(handler) {

    logger.log('info', 'Setting up routes.')

    router.use(bodyParser.json);

    router.get('/', (req, res) => {
        logger.log('info', '/');
        res.send('Home Page');
    });

    router.get('/quotes', (req, res) => {
        logger.log('info', '/quotes');
        res.send('/quotes');
    });

    return router;
}
```

The `handler` being passed to routes is meant to hold the functions that will be called by the routes.

I'm obviously missing something but I can't figure out what it is, so if anyone has any idea it'll be greatly appreciated.

Quick note: if I pass `app` to the routing module and call `app.use('/', router)` right before `return router`, it works fine. But that completely defeats the purpose of splitting this into two modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [use `bodyParser.json` as a function](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserjsonoptions).
To fix the problem, just change

```
router.use(bodyParser.json);
```

to

```
router.use(bodyParser.json());
```

The reason it won't work because `bodyParser.json` is a function. When you call it as a function it returns the proper middleware for express. If you don't call it as a function, it references the function that returns the middleware. To continue on you must call `next()` in the express middleware, but if you don't call `bodyParser.json` as a function it will never call `next()`.

Comment: Oh come on that was actually it, I can't believe I missed that. I'm also surprised this didn't raise any error or warning.
Well thanks a lot anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
router.get('/', (req, res){
  logger.log('info', '/');
  res.render('index', {
    title: 'Home'
  });
});
```

Comment: No luck with that unfortunately. The log messages in the routes don't get printed in the first place so I'm pretty positive the routes don't get called at all.